# Kubernetes hpa can't get memory metrics (when it is clearly stated)

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to implement autoscaling of pods in my cluster. I have tried with a "dummy" deployment and hpa, and I didn't have problem. Now, I am trying to integrate it into our "real" microservices and it keeps returning

```
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: missing request for memory
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                   From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       18m (x5 over 19m)     horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource memory: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  18m (x5 over 19m)     horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get memory utilization: unable to get metrics for resource memory: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  16m (x7 over 18m)     horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get memory utilization: missing request for memory
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       4m38s (x56 over 18m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  missing request for memory
```

Here is my hpa:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: #{Name}
 namespace: #{Namespace}
spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   name: #{Name}
 minReplicas: 2
 maxReplicas: 5
 metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
```

The deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: #{Name}
  namespace: #{Namespace}
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: #{Name}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: enabled
      labels:
        app: #{Name}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: #{Name}
        image: #{image}
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: "300Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: "200Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: #{ContainerPort}
```

I can see both memory and cpu when I do `kubectl top pods`.  I can see the requests and limits as well when I do `kubectl describe pod`.

```
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  300Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  200Mi
```

The only difference I can think of is that my dummy service didn't have linkerd sidecar.

Comment: is metric server deployed?

Comment: Yes, the dummy service is in the same cluster as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the HPA to work with resource metrics, *every* container of the Pod needs to have a request for the given resource (CPU or memory).

It seems that the Linkerd sidecar container in your Pod does not define a memory request (it might have a CPU request). That's why the HPA complains about `missing request for memory`.

However, you can configure the memory and CPU requests for the Linkerd container with the `--proxy-cpu-request` and `--proxy-memory-request` [injection flags](https://linkerd.io/2/reference/cli/inject/).

Another possibility is to use [these annotations](https://linkerd.io/2/reference/proxy-configuration/) to configure the CPU and memory requests:

- `config.linkerd.io/proxy-cpu-request`
- `config.linkerd.io/proxy-memory-request`

Defining a memory request with in either of these ways should make the HPA work.

**References:**

- Linkerd issue initially reported [in this issue](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/1480) and fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/pull/1731)
- In [Linkerd 2.3.0](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/blob/master/CHANGES.md#stable-230), `--proxy-cpu-request` and `--proxy-memory-request` replaced `--proxy-cpu` and `--proxy-memory`
- There was a similar issue with the [Istio sidecar](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13977), but it seems to have been fixed too

Comment: Hello! You were absolutely right. I found out it was linkerd a couple of hours after posting and haven't had the time to update yet. We updated the deployment with those config (https://linkerd.io/2/reference/proxy-configuration/) and it works now. thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @shrimpy Can you please update your deployment manifest to reflect what you did to correct it? Thanks.

Comment: @shrimpy, nvm. I guess they fixed it now with the latest Kubernetes v1.20 that I'm using.